# TypeScript Convert Observable<Student[]>[] to Observable<Student[]>

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I am trying to process student collection, and for each student call different server api, how can I combine the response from differnt api?

Here is a demo code for issue:

```
  test4(students:Student[]):Observable<Student[]> {
    var rr = students.map(student =>{
      if (student.age === 1) {
        return this.client
          .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
          .pipe(
            map((res) => {
              console.log(res);
              student.age = student.age * 100;
              return [student];
            })
          );
      } else {
        return this.client
          .get('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json')
          .pipe(
            map((res) => {
              console.log(res);
              student.age = student.age * 10000;
              return [student];
            })
          );
      }
    });
  }
```

If possible, I would not prefer use forkjoin.

**Update**

I have such source data

```
 getStudents(): Student[] {
    return [{ age: 1 }, { age: 2 }, { age: 3 }];
  }
```

If age = 1, then return 1*100; If age >1 then return 1*10000; before *100 or *10000, it will send request to different api, I mocked the http request within abovde code

The input and output for function will be `test4(students: Student[]): Observable<Student[]>` Which means the final result will be something like `of([{ age: 100 }, { age: 20000 }, { age: 30000 }])`.
I have another function to call `test4` like below:

```
  test() {
    this.test4(this.getStudents())
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          return of([]);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

And it will log something like `[{ age: 100 }, { age: 20000 }, { age: 30000 }]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is one possible solution, use `from` to convert array to observable stream. The `concatMap` will execute the api sequentially and finally `toArray()` will group all the outputs into an array.

```
import './style.css';

import { of, map, from } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap, toArray } from 'rxjs/operators';

from([{ age: 1 }, { age: 4 }])
  .pipe(
    concatMap((student) => {
      return from(
        fetch('https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json').then((res) =>
          res.json()
        )
      ).pipe(
        map((res) => {
          console.log(res);
          student.age = student.age * (student.age === 1 ? 100 : 10000);
          return student;
        })
      );
    }),
    toArray(),
  )
  .subscribe((output) => console.log(output));
```

Output:

```
[Object, Object]
0: Object
age: 100
__proto__: Object
1: Object
age: 40000
__proto__: Object
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-nrqmd8)

Based on latest input you need to modify results and return with `of` operator to get an observable.

```
 getStudents(): Student[] {
    return [{ age: 1 }, { age: 2 }, { age: 3 }];
  }

test4(inputArray: Array<Student>): Observable<Student[]> {
    return of(inputArray.map((student) => {
        student.age = student.age * (student.age === 1 ? 100 : 10000);
        return student;
    })
}

 test() {
    this.test4(this.getStudents())
      .pipe(
        mergeMap((result) => {
          console.log(result);
          return of([]);
        })
      )
      .subscribe();
  }
```

Comment: Is it split array into two blok? for example, I have `[{ age: 1 }, { age: 2 },{ age: 4 }]`, for `[{ age: 1 },{ age: 2 }]`, request api1, `[{ age: 4 }]`, send request to api2, and `[{ age: 1 },{ age: 2 }]` should be send to api1 within one request instead of loop this array to send two different request.

Comment: in question you shared you want Observable<Student[]> please show the expected output of the code, based on the example I provided.

Comment: I update the input and output in original post, please help to check

Comment: @Edward updated, if want to iterate through each element in the array, use my first answer